# After restoring a HyperV snapshot, I get "the trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed"

Tags: active-directory, hyper-v, remote-desktop, snapshot

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 HyperV machine.  I had to restore it to an old snapshot, and now I'm getting the following error when logging in through remote desktop using a domain ID:

```
"the trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed"
```

I tried running

```
netdom resetpwd /s:server.company.lab /ud:na\domainAdminId /pd:password
```

But it didn't help.  I tried resetting the password and rebooting the server, but it didn't help.

Any ideas?

Comment: and the basics work like nslookup fqdn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command I ran actually worked, it just took several minutes for it to take effect for some reason.

```
netdom resetpwd /s:server.company.lab /ud:na\domainAdminId /pd:password
```

I'm not sure why.  I think somebody was rebooting some of the AD servers at the time I ran the command, so that could have thrown things off.

Comment: I used `netdom resetpwd /s:mydomserver.dom.com /userd sysadminJoe /PasswordD * `  on the server which has a trust issue. (login to localhost)

Answer (score 3):

Try netdom reset : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc788073(WS.10).aspx

Comment: did he edit and add the part about running netdom?

Comment: @tony I don't know, but nedom reset != netdom resetpwd